# YouTube Playlist inside a Page with x-amount of videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I want to display a YouTube Playlist, where i have the main/current selected video in the top and x-amount of videos of that playlist underneath it.

Sadly it seems to stop inside the function loadVids right before $.getJSON, but i cant seem to find the error here.

(I had a typo at options being opions, but that isn't the problem here)

HTML:

```
<div class="vidcontainer">
    <section id="video"></section>
    <main class="video-playlist"></main>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var key = 'myKey';
    var playlistId = 'myPlaylist';
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';
    var options = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: key,
        maxResults: 20,
        playlistId: playlistId
    };
    
    loadVids();

    function loadVids() {
        $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
            var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            mainVid(id);
            resultsLoop(data);
        });
    }
    
    function mainVid(id) {
        $('#video').html(`
            <div class="responsive-video">
                <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        `);
    }

    function resultsLoop(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
            var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            var title = item.snippet.title;
            var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 100);
            var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    
            $('main.video-playlist').append(`
                <varticle class="item" data-key="${vid}">
                    <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="vidthumb">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4 style="float:left;font-size: 20px;font-family: sauna-boldregular;margin-bottom: 16px;">${title}</h4>
                        <p style="float:left;">${desc}…</p>
                    </div>
                </varticle>
            `);
        });
    }

    // CLICK EVENT
    $('main.video-playlist').on('click', 'varticle', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-key');
        mainVid(id);
        document.getElementById('video').scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure you use the correct api-key and the correct id for the playlistId, this looks like PL742CF1A8BF939A

Comment: I had generated a new key around 5 times just for that and also the playlistId was like 5 times checked.
That cant really be that :/
My console says "$.getJSON is not a function" and i researched on that, but no matter how i include the JQuery Scripts i still get that error.
At this point iam not sure if my Script up there is wrong or something else...

Comment: I made a fiddle with your code and replaced the keys with my keys and no problem, all worked fine. Make sure you load your jquery properly. Here is the fiddle, just assign the proper keys. https://jsfiddle.net/c3pqtek7/ @Grimclaw Draven

Comment: So i changed my loadVids to this:
function loadVids() {
    console.log($(".breadcrumb-item")[0]);
    $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
        var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
        mainVid(id);
        resultsLoop(data);
    });
}

and the console responds with my selected element and these two errors right after:

"jQuery.Deferred exception: $.getJSON is not a function TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function"

"Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function"

Comment: I use this tag in my header now, so i load it at the right time:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Does the fiddle work with your keys?

Comment: Yes it does, also I found a solution now.
I had to download the current version and include it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downloading and including jQuery instead of using it from external source, the problem is gone.
Get it from here and make sure to get the compressed production version: https://jquery.com/download/